# Coroutines multiple asynchronous tasks and measure tasks time

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How do we design a structure in Kotlin Coroutines to run multiple asynchronous tasks in parallel, collect their results, and measure the time for each task to complete?

Just a small code example is enough for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```
suspend fun performAsyncOperation(id: Int): String {
    delay(1000)
    return "Result $id"
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val ids = 1..10

    val deferredResults = ids.map { id ->
        async {
            val elapsedTime = measureTimeMillis {
                val result = performAsyncOperation(id)
                println("Task $id completed. Result: $result")
            }
            println("Task $id took $elapsedTime ms")
        }
    }

    deferredResults.awaitAll()

    println("All tasks completed.")
}
```